# how to put icons in drawer flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to put icons in the left hand side of drawer's children like this photo
[image]

is there any specific widgets to do something like this?

my drawer code is this

```
Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('forms'),
            onTap: () { //and rest of the code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `leading` property of `ListTile` widget to add an `Icon`.

```dart
ListTile(
  onTap: () {},
  leading: Icon(Icons.add),
  title: Text('Add'),
);
```